# Ubuntu openstack single installer on ubuntu 15.10 Wily

Tags: juju, openstack, lxc

The only release I can successfully run the entire single-installer on is 14.04.

Since then on 15.04 and now on 15.10 I cannot get the single-installer to succeed.

on 15.10 I have tried each of the following at diff times:

```
sudo openstack-install --series wily --openstack-release liberty
sudo openstack-install --series trusty --openstack-release liberty
sudo openstack-install -series wily
```

None have worked and each exhibits a different type of error/failure.

`lxc-attach` to the openstack-single-$USER container setting the juju env and then running `juju status` shows there's a mix of Trusty & Wily installed no matter what I specify for `--series`.

I only mention that because I saw an email from Mike McCracken regarding that mixture being a problem that would have to get fixed by the devs.

Has anyone gotten the `single-installer` to finish successfully on Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) and, if so, I'd like to know how you did it?

Additionally, I've followed all of these guides and have tried on multiple machines many times:

http://openstack.astokes.org/guides/single-install

and

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer

Comment: Hey Brian, there are a couple of issues on Wily wrt the single installer, we are currently testing those fixes and some additional ones before we release an update into the archive. In the meantime you can use the experimental ppa with `--upstream-ppa` to run the installer on Wily. Like I said though there are a "few" issues some installer related and some not (juju).

Answer (score 2):

I just used sudo openstack-install --openstack-release liberty

also in my homedir created a directory .juju and created environments.yaml with the following

```
environments:
 maas:
  type: maas
  maas-server: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/MAAS'          
  maas-oauth: 'YOUR MAAS API KEY'
  admin-secret: 'YOUR ADMIN SECRET'
 default-series: wily
```

You may have to muck with the yaml formatting if you copy/paste, then run the installer.